# 32-bit unicode in python

Tags: python, unicode

Python has an escape sequence `\u` to display unicode values. However this is restricted to only 16 bit unicode values. That is

```
>>> '\u1020'
'ဠ'
```

Whereas 32 bit uncode values do not work. That is

```
>>> '\u00001000'
'\x001000'
```

Which is obviously wrong. The python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#unicode-strings) mentions

> The escape sequence \u0020 indicates to insert the Unicode character with the ordinal value 0x0020 (the space character) at the given position.

Comment: note: it is misleading to talk about `n`-bit Unicode. The numbers after `\u` and `\U` are 16 and 32 bit hexadecimal numbers (it just means that there are 4 and 8 hex digits correspondingly) but it says nothing about how many bytes it takes to serialize the corresponding Unicode codepoint into bytes (bits) e.g., ['\u044F'](http://codepoints.net/U+044F) is 2 bytes in `utf-8` encoding but it is a single byte in `cp1251`.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian then how else should I frame my question? Please educate me on that.

Comment: "how to specify non-BMP Unicode character in Python string literal?" Or `"how to use Unicode escape `\uXXXX` for Unicode codepoints > 0xFFFF?"` Don't change your title. Other people may have the same misconception and it may be useful for them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The python [How To Unicode](https://docs.python.org/3.4/howto/unicode.html#the-string-type) clearly mentions the use of `'\U'` to represent 32-bit unicode sequences.

```
>>> "\u0394"                          # Using a 16-bit hex value
'Δ'
>>> "\U00000394"                      # Using a 32-bit hex value
'Δ'
```

In this case

```
>>> '\U00001000'
'က'
```